# Which is the best way to deal with table, when we have more than 500 expandable list in a view page?

Tags: tables, lists, accordion, multi-column

I have a view page in my application wherein I am listing the number of devices along with the device configuration details like protocol, Broker Ip, Payloads etc. I have designed this list in such a way that it expands on click and shows the detailed information.

As we add more devices, this list keeps expanding and it can go on for more than 500 or up to 1000 in some scenarios.

So what is the best way to deal with such complex expandable table list?

[image]

Comment: Why are you displaying the list? What would people do with the expanded information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best possible way to handle your situation is to implement **Master Detail Pattern** in your design.

Check out information regarding Master Detail Views [here](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/ux/middleware/alta/patterns/MasterDetail.html)

> It would make it easy for the users to view details of a selected item
>   side by side without cluttering the list view. Reference wire-frame is
>   attached below which illustrates the concept of Master Detail View.

[image]